# Problema ao fazer a ligação entre tabelas utilizando uma Foreign key

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Boa tarde, estou com um pequeno problema ao fazer a ligação entre as tabelas, preciso ligar a tabela de atleta e fazer a ligação com a tabela do orgão expedidor de documento.
Aparece o seguinte erro quando tento criar a tabela de atleta:

**“Error code 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint.”**

Eu já criei a tabela modalidade, naipe e orgao_ex.
Se alguém puder me falar qual o erro agradeço.

Segue abaixo as queries:

```
CREATE TABLE modalidade (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT uk_id UNIQUE (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE naipe (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT uk_id UNIQUE (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE competicao (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
modalidade INT NOT NULL,
naipe INT NOT NULL,
inicio DATETIME,
fim DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT uk_id UNIQUE (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_modalidade FOREIGN KEY (modalidade)
REFERENCES modalidade,
CONSTRAINT fk_naipe FOREIGN KEY (naipe)
REFERENCES naipe
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE relac_atleta (
competicao INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
atleta INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT uk_competicao UNIQUE (compteticao),
CONSTRAINT uk_atleta UNIQUE (atleta),
CONSTRAINT fk_competicao FOREIGN KEY (competicao)
REFERENCES competicao,
constraint fk_atleta foreign key (atleta)
references atleta
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE orgao_exp (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
descricao VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
sigla VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT _uk_id UNIQUE (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE atleta (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
rg VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
orgao INT NOT NULL,
uf_rg CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_orgao FOREIGN KEY (orgao)
REFERENCES orgao_exp (orgao)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Em qual tabela essa FK está e em qual tabela ela será ligada?

Comment: sua tabela orgao_exp não tem o campo orgao....

Comment: O Lucas está certo

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro utilizar um software para modelar o banco de dados e gerar SQL automático. Utilizo o freeware [DBDesigner4](http://fabforce.eu/dbdesigner4/). Dividir em duas etapas, a criação da tabela  e posteriormente a modificação com inclusão das chaves.

Comment: Boa tarde primeiramente agradeço o seu tempo e disponibilidade para responder a minha pergunta.
Então amigo, essa tabela é uma atividade do curso técnico onde estudo, tem que ser feito manualmente a modelagem utilizando o MySQL, mas agradeço pela dica irei utilizar na criação de outros bancos de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Em sua tabela orgao_exp não existe o campo orgao, que você está referenciando na tabela ATLETA.

```
CREATE TABLE orgao_exp (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
--orgao
descricao VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
sigla VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT _uk_id UNIQUE (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```